# Find maximum value of a continuous function at a specific resolution

Tags: c#, algorithm

Imagine having a function that is continuous over a range [0.0,n]. Are there any algorithms to find the maximum value of the function given a minimum step size `s` more quickly than simple iteration? The simple iteration is straightforward to program but the time complexity grows when `n / s` is large.

```
double maxValue = 0;
double maxValueX = 0;
double s = 0.1 * n;
for (double x = 0.0; x <= n; x += s)
{
     double value = someFunction(x);
     if(value > maxValue) {
         maxValue = value;
         maxValueX = x;
     }
}
```

I have tried this approach which is much quicker, but don't know if it will get stuck on local maximums.

```
double min = 0;
double max = n;
int steps = 10;
increment = (max - min) / steps;
while (increment > s)
{
    double maxValue = 0;
    double maxValueX = X;
    for (double x= min; x <= max; x+= increment)
    {
         double value = someFunction(x);
         if(value > maxValue) {
             maxValue = value;
             maxValueX = x;
         }
    }
    min = Math.Max(maxValueX - increment, 0.0);
    max = Math.Min(maxValueX + increment, n);
    increment = (max - min) / steps;
}
```

Comment: If f(x) is continuous, max values (also min values) appears at d/dx f(x) = 0. While there's no information about the degree of the function and evaluating the function only by calling it, this is likely the only method. Furthermore, as you increase the steps, you may have a more "close to max" value unless there's other known restriction on the domain value (i.e. possible value of x).

Comment: You need `f` to be differentiable if you want to look at `d/dx f(x)`.  There are many functions that are continuous but not differentiable.

Comment: If you know something about how continuous `f` is, that could help.  For example, if `|f(x+s)-f(x)|` is bounded, then when `f` is far from its maximum, you can take larger steps.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose there was such an algorithm, that is, an algorithm that can find the maximum of an approximation of a continuous function without looking at every point of the approximation.

Now choose a positive integer n and choose any finite sequence of n doubles you care to name. There are infinitely many continuous functions such that f(n) is equal to the nth double in the sequence, and smaller than or equal to the largest of them everywhere.  Choose one of them.

Now use your algorithm to find the largest double of the n doubles. By assumption, it examines fewer than n of the doubles. Let's suppose it examines all of them except the kth double.

Now suppose we create a new sequence identical to the first one except that the kth double is the maximum.  Is the algorithm magical, that when given an input *that it does not read*, it changes its output?

Now is it clear why there is no such algorithm? If you want to find the longest piece of string in the drawer, you're going to have to look at all of them.

The continuity of the function doesn't help you at all. All continuity gives you is a guarantee that given a point on the function, you can find another point on the function that is as close to the first point as you like. That tells you nothing about the maximum value taken on by the function.  (Well, OK, it tells you *something*. On a closed bounded interval it implies that a maximum exists, which is something. But it doesn't help you find it.)

Comment: I think you're counterexample is a little disingenuous: changing the kth double changes the "shape" of the function therefore there could, theoretically, be an algorithm that would initially dismiss the kth value due to specific local boundary conditions that would otherwise not be met if the kth value was a local or global maximum.

Comment: @InBetween: I do not appreciate being called disingenuous, particularly in public. I am neither insincere in my attempt to honestly answer the question nor am I attempting to pretend that I know more about calculus than I do. We all do better on this site when we attribute the best of intentions to everyone else.

Comment: @InBetween: To address your specific concern: take a new function g(x) that is equal to f(x) at all points except between k-0.00000001 and k+0.0000001, and a continuous function of your choice between those points.

Comment: I didn't call *you* disingenuous, I qualified your answer in this particular case. My native language is not english so I was not aware that *disingenuous* could be so offendig. I apologize. And your last comment does not solve my concern at all. It all depends on the granularity of the search you are doing: if it isn't small enough, you won't catch the maximum even if you inspect all points. If its small enough then you will *see* enough information to know something fishy close to `k`. Obviously if you are so unlucky as to choose .0000002 as your step then you could be in trouble.

Comment: And of course, if the interval where g(x) has a "different behavior" is infinitely small then we have a function that is not continuous and therefore not relevant to what is being asked.

Comment: Doubles aren't infinite in number though, there only 2^64-1 of them. And since I am only concerned with positives values below N, the number is bounded to 2^32-1

Comment: @InBetween: Apology accepted. "Disingenuous" implies that the speaker is making a *deliberate* attempt to deceive their listener with a bad argument; it describes the motives of the **speaker**. A better word to use in this case would have been "specious", which describes the **argument**; a specious argument is one which appears plausible but is in fact invalid. I may have advanced a specious argument, but if I did, it was in good faith.

Comment: @InBetween: Changing the kth double may change the shaape of the algorithm, but this change in shape is only visible if you make use of the kth point (possibly indirectly, e.g., by calculating the angle between k and another point).  For example, consider a circle inscribed in a pentagon ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/U8iop.gif ).  If we examine only the 5 points shared between the circle and the pentagon, we will not know whether we are looking at a circle, a pentagon, or some other shape, as there are multiple such shapes which share these points.

Comment: @Brian: not necessarily true in all scenarios: if `d/dx f(nk-1)` and `d/dx f(nk+1)` are both not equal to zero and have the same sign then you can be pretty sure that `f(nk)` is not a local or global maximum/minimum without needing to evaluate the function in `nk`. This is true of course if `n(k+1)-nk` is small enough. If it isn't you have more serious problems because you are probably missing the maximum value alltogether to begin with.

Comment: @InBetween: Your point is well taken, but I note that no one said that the continuous function was differentiable anywhere.

Comment: Point taken. Still your answer seems to imply that iterating over the whole `nk` set is the only solution. I'm just clarifying that it's not necessarily true in all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Given the function you are talking about is code, then no, that function could return any arbitrary maximum at any point.

If you can make assumptions about the function ( like maximum rate of change ) then you could optimize.